# How do I prevent the wp_editor from loading outside container?

Tags: wp-editor

I'm trying to load the wp_editor on a settings page:

```
<?php

                            //$content = $value->playerBio;
                            $editor_id = 'listingIntro';
                            $textareaname = "listingIntro";
                            $settings = array("textarea_name" => $textareaname);

                            wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings);

                        ?>
```

the editor is loading outside the table. Can I force it to load inside the table?